# LiqPay: Статус платежа

Tags: php, api, платежи

LiqPay [предоставляет](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/information/status/doc) возможность проверять статус платежа по `order_id`.

1. Собственно вопрос касается дат `create_date` и `end_date`. Они в странном формате и просто так сконвертировать их из `timestamp` в обычную дату не получается. Как это можно сделать?
2. Второй вопрос касается проверки статуса [подписки](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/subscribe/doc) `subscribe`. На момент оплаты, как видно из приведенного примера ответа, возвращает `'result' => 'ok'`, но вот что оно будет возвращать в случае не успешной оплаты подписки, скажем, на второй месяц и будет ли вообще возвращать? В документации ничего по этому поводу не сказано.

Возвращает примерно следующее:

```
object(stdClass)[6090]


  public 'result' => string 'ok' (length=2)
  public 'action' => string 'subscribe' (length=9)
  public 'payment_id' => int 1111111111
  public 'status' => string 'sandbox' (length=7)
  public 'version' => int 3
  public 'type' => string 'buy' (length=3)
  public 'paytype' => string 'card' (length=4)
  public 'public_key' => string 'sandbox_i1111111' (length=19)
  public 'acq_id' => int 1111111
  public 'order_id' => string '57' (length=2)
  public 'liqpay_order_id' => string 'RQVEL8SD15735ХХХХХХХХХ' (length=24)
  public 'description' => string 'Покупка One Month Subscription' (length=37)
  public 'sender_phone' => string '380ХХХХХХХХХ' (length=12)
  public 'sender_first_name' => string 'V.' (length=2)
  public 'sender_last_name' => string 'Фамилия' (length=6)
  public 'sender_card_mask2' => string '516911*11' (length=9)
  public 'sender_card_bank' => string 'pb' (length=2)
  public 'sender_card_type' => string 'mc' (length=2)
  public 'sender_card_country' => int 804
  public 'ip' => string '1.1.1.1' (length=13)
  public 'amount' => float 269.62
  public 'currency' => string 'UAH' (length=3)
  public 'sender_commission' => float 0
  public 'receiver_commission' => float 7.41
  public 'agent_commission' => float 0
  public 'amount_debit' => float 269.62
  public 'amount_credit' => float 269.62
  public 'commission_debit' => float 0
  public 'commission_credit' => float 7.41
  public 'currency_debit' => string 'UAH' (length=3)
  public 'currency_credit' => string 'UAH' (length=3)
  public 'sender_bonus' => float 0
  public 'amount_bonus' => float 0
  public 'mpi_eci' => string '7' (length=1)
  public 'is_3ds' => boolean false
  public 'language' => string 'ru' (length=2)
  public 'create_date' => int 1573562259599
  public 'end_date' => int 1573562259611
  public 'transaction_id' => int 1167120959
```

Comment: `1573562259599` разделите на 1000.

Comment: @u_mulder Благодарю! А с чем это связано? То есть timestamp до этого умножали на 1000 или что?

Comment: С тем что есть микросекунды.

Comment: @u_mulder Да, действительно. Стыдно признаться, до этого нигде не использовал.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926749/how-to-convert-a-13-digit-unix-timestamp-to-date-and-time/32926762#32926762

Answer (score 0):

Что касается второго вопроса, скорее всего будет отдаваться текущее состояние подписки. Также возвращается статус списания подписки на server-url компании.

[image: Схема работы подписок LiqPay]